# SQLAlchemy @property causes 'Unknown Field' error in Marshmallow with dump_only

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I'm using flask-marshmallow (marshmallow=v3.0.0rc1, flask-marshmallow=0.9.0) and flask-sqlalchemy (sqlalchemy=1.2.16, flask-sqlalchemy=2.3.2)

I have this model and schema.

```
from marshmallow import post_load, fields
from .datastore import sqla_database as db
from .extensions import marshmallow as ma

class Study(db.Model):
    _id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

    tests = db.relationship("Test", backref="study", lazy='select', cascade="all, delete-orphan")

    @property
    def test_count(self):
        return len(self.tests)

class StudySchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    test_count = fields.Integer(dump_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Study
        sqla_session = db.session

schema = StudySchema()
payload = request.get_json()
schema.load(data=payload, instance=Study.query.get(payload["_id"]))
schema.session.commit()
```

If I perform a PUT operation with this payload
`{'_id': 1, 'name': 'Study1', 'test_count': 0}` I get the following exception `marshmallow.exceptions.ValidationError: {'test_count': ['Unknown field.']}`

If I remove the `dump_only=True` I get this exception `AttributeError: can't set attribute` which makes sense to me because it's trying to set test_count with no setter method on model class.

What I do not understand is why is the attribute is not ignored with `dump_only`. Why is marshmallow still trying to validate and understand this field during load when it's marked as `dump_only`?

Comment: What is your marshmallow and flask-marshmallow versions?

Comment: sqlalchemy=1.2.16
flask-sqlalchemy=2.3.2
marshmallow=v3.0.0rc1
flask-marshmallow=0.9.0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In marshmallow 2, unknown or dump_only fields are ignored from input. Unless the user decides to add his own validation to error on them.

In marshmallow 3, we changed that to offer three possibilities (see [docs](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/upgrading.html#schemas-raise-validationerror-when-deserializing-data-with-unknown-keys)):

- RAISE (default)
- EXCLUDE (like marshmallow 2)
- INCLUDE (pass data without validation)

There's been discussions about how to deal with dump_only fields and we came to the conclusion that from client perspective, those should be treated just as unknown fields (see https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/issues/875).

Bottom line, your PUT payload should not include dump_only fields. Or you could set the EXCLUDE policy to your schema, but I'd favor the former option.

Comment: This is exactly the information I needed. Thank you!