# Deserialize available fields in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-3.7, marshmallow

I currently have a dataclass:

```
@dataclass
class User(object):
    login: str
    email: str
```

when registering the user I receive JSON of the following format:

```
{
    "login": "lg",
    "email": "e@ma.il"
    "password": "some password"
}
```

and parse it with `marshmallow` as

```
import marshmallow_dataclass

json = #the json
user = marshmallow_dataclass.class_schema(User)().load(json)
```

I got

```
marshmallow.exceptions.ValidationError: {'password': ['Unknown field.']}
```

I'd like to throw fields that are not used in the Schema, but are presented in JSON away. Is there a way to do this with marshmallow?

Comment: [According to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54391524/sqlalchemy-property-causes-unknown-field-error-in-marshmallow-with-dump-only), it looks like you can pass `unknown=marshmallow.EXCLUDE` to `load`.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Very cool. Thanks!